# lines passing through two points in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projection, projective-varieties

The reference is the Example 7.5. b) from ag notes by Gathmann. The paragraph explains the idea of projection from a point. He claims that the unique line passing through $a=(1:0:\cdots:0)\in\mathbb{P}^n$ and $x\in\mathbb{P}^n-\{a\}$ can be parametrized by
$$P:=\{(s:tx_1:tx_2:\cdots:tx_n)|(s:t)\in\mathbb{P}^1\}$$
However, I think, the point $a$ would correspond to an actual line in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ as below
$$L_a=\{(s,0,\cdots,0)\in\mathbb{A}^{n+1}|s\in k\}$$
and the point $x$ corresponds to the line
$$L_x=\{(tx_0,\cdots,tx_n)|t\in k\}$$
Hence the "line passing through them in $\mathbb{P}^n$" should be something like a plane, or a linear combination of these two lines in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, i.e.
$$P_{a,x}=\{(s+tx_0,tx_1,\cdots,tx_n)\in\mathbb{A}^{n+1}|s,t\in k\}$$
Then I do not see how do we get $P$ from $P_{a,x}$ by simply projectivization. The $tx_0$ part disappears. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are the same linear subspace but different parametrizations. Can you see why?

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your hint. Is it because we can scale the $s$ in $L_a$ to be $s-tx_0$ for arbitrary $t\in k$?. And this new definition $L_a=\{(s+tx_0,0,\cdots,0)|s,t\in k\}$ is still the same line as before?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to see it. Another is that if one lets $s'=s-tx_0$, then $s'a+tx=sa+tx$, so the two sets are the same up to an automorphism of the $\Bbb P^1$ parametrizing them.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you so much!

Comment: It would be helpful for people reading your question to give the complete reference https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/de/alggeom.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helps and suggestions from comments, I post my own answer here:
We scale $L_a$ so that $L_a=\{(s+tx_0:0:\cdots:0)|s,t\in k\}$. Then by looking at the linear combination of the new $L_a$ and $L_x$, we are able to solve it.